# Debug not working with_items in ansible play

Tags: ansible

Need some help in debug the specific value from register task.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: path_result.results
```

This is not working

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "path_result": {
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "changed": true,
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "stderr_lines": [],
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "end": "2019-04-10 14:55:18.726270",
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_delegated_vars": {
                    "ansible_delegated_host": "**.***.***.***",
                    "ansible_host": "**.***.***.***"
                },
                "cmd": "cat /tmp/abc.conf | grep apple",
                "rc": 0,
                "stdout": "fruit=apple",
                "item": "**.***.***.***",
                "delta": "0:00:00.021499",
                "stderr": "",
                "changed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "creates": null,
                        "executable": null,
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "_raw_params": "cat /tmp/abc.conf | grep apple",
                        "removes": null,
                        "warn": true,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "stdin": null
                    }
                },
                "stdout_lines": [
                    "fruit=apple"
                ],
                "start": "2019-04-10 14:55:18.704771",
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "failed": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

I would like to debug this particular output:

```
"stdout": "fruit=apple"
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have `register`ed the result of a play with: `register: path_result`.  That variable ALSO has `path_result` inside it.  Here's what I think you have:

```
- command: cat /tmp/abc.conf | grep apple
  register: path_result

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ path_result.results }}"
```

Here's what I think you need:

```
- command: cat /tmp/abc.conf | grep apple
  register: path_result

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ path_result.path_result.results }}"
```

Notice the added `.path_result` part in `with_items`.

Comment: I tried the one you gave and getting this error : 

{
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'playbook.yml': line 10, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"
} @jack

Comment: - shell: cat /tmp/abc.conf | grep apple
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups.rhel7 }}"
    register: path_result
  
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    with_items: path_result.path_result.results

this is what i used in my play

Comment: Forgot to dereference the `with_items` variable.  Fixing it now.